# Add input and show output in terminal from .desktop file

Tags: bash, icons, linux-mint, openconnect

I have bash script which connect to my vpn.

bash script - Openconnect.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo openconnect --protocol=gp 15.115.16.145
```

Openconnect.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my VPN Connection
Exec=/home/support/Documents/Openconnect.sh
Icon=/home/support/Documents/openvpn.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

When we execute only bash script it asks me for user and password then for confirmation.

However when we execute Openconnect.desktop it doesn't show in terminal window to provide input.
I am using Linx Mint 18 OS.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `.desktop` are text files... Why are you trying to execute it?

Comment: Idea is to create application instead of running command manually. So from Launcher double click in Openconnect Icon and it should ask for Username/password and confirmation.

Comment: So you double click the application and it does nothing?

Comment: Yes, It does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, First install lxterminal and then edit Openconnect.desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Openconnect
Comment=This is my VPN Connection
Exec=lxterminal --command="/home/support/Documents/Openconnect.sh"
Icon=/home/support/Documents/openvpn.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```